2D unity GameObject Tag Causes Unexpected Behavior After Collision
code
It seems like the problem is that the tag is 2 in the 2 colliding prefabs. or not ıdk
With this code, I want two prefabs with the "2" tag to collide and disappear, and instead of them, I want a prefab with the "4" tag to appear, but 2 prefabs with the "4" tag are created. How to fix this?
if this is a stupid question, i'm just newbie

prefabs cant disappear because they arent real, they are like recipies. (terminology matters) The problem is this code runs on both items marked 2.  because they both collide, you need a system that picks 1 of the 2..

Destroy call is not immediate. It happens at the end of the frame and the other "2" object's OnCollisionEnter2D is also getting called before end of frame.
You could either maintain a state using a variable like isDestroyed that is set for the other colliding object. Then only spawn the prefab child if isDestroyed is false:
public bool isDestroyed = false;

private void OnCollisionEnter2D(Collision2D collision)
{
  if (collision.gameObject.CompareTag("2"))
  {
    // Set other object's isDestroyed to true
    collision.transform.GetComponent<GameManager>().isDestroyed = true;
    // Destroy the other object
    Destroy(collision.gameObject);

    // Do not create another prefab for "4" if this is destroyed
    if (!isDestroyed)
      Instantiate(newPrefab, transform.position, Quaternion.identity);
  }
}

Edit: As stated by Ömer Faruk Bal, DestroyImmediate does not work in a physics collision callback. So please ignore the rest of the post in context of physics callbacks.
Unity also provides DestroyImmediate which destroys object immediately instead of waiting till end of frame, but is not recommended to be used in most cases: https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Object.DestroyImmediate.html

still same and
Destroying GameObjects immediately is not permitted during physics trigger/contact, animation event callbacks, rendering callbacks or OnValidate. You must use Destroy instead.

I tested and my first solution code is working exactly as expected. Please check and test it again.
You are correct about my second option that DestroyImmediate does not work with collision callback.  I will update my answer to include this info.

Also, please add your code to the question instead of a link to a screenshot of the code
